# Generate not enough data SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I used the following query to generate 488 rows of tuples in Mac Terminal, but it only generated 420 rows. I sent this query to my friend, and generated 488 rows with my query on his Mac. Wrong queries I made for this assignment can generate up to thousands of rows. My Mac is MacBook Pro 2016, and I keep it carefully like an egg, so it should not have hardware issues. Please share your ideas to solve this problem. I appreciate a lot.

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.name, f1.flight_num, f1.origin_city, f1.dest_city, 
f1.actual_time ,
f2.flight_num, f2.origin_city, f2.dest_city, f2.actual_time ,
(f1.actual_time + f2.actual_time)/60
FROM Flights f1, Flights f2, Carriers c, Months m
WHERE f1.carrier_id = f2.carrier_id AND f1.carrier_id = c.cid 
AND f1.day_of_month = f2.day_of_month AND f1.day_of_month = 15
AND f1.year = f2.year AND f1.year = 2015
AND f1.month_id = f2.month_id AND f1.month_id = m.mid AND f2.month_id = 
m.mid AND m.month ='July'
AND f1.origin_city ='Seattle WA' AND f2.dest_city ='Boston MA' AND 
f1.dest_city = f2.origin_city
AND (f1.actual_time + f2.actual_time )<60*7;
```

Comment: Some information about table structures and some sample data would be very helpful, perhaps also a description in words of what this query is supposed to do.

Comment: A few questions: is this a local database that you have separate copies of? If so that brings two possibilities: either differences in the underlying data or differences in the config of the database. If it's a shared database, then that cant be the issue. However you may be using different tools to query the data or have chosen different config settings for that tool. Pay particular attention to any settings relating to treatment of nulls and date/time settings.

Comment: This is a local database. I guess the problem is at settling .